# IRC client that saves identity information

Tags: irc

I have tried more than a handful of clients. For some reason we still need to use arcane knowledge such as

/msg NICKSERV IDENTIFY

Can anybody recommend an ncurses client that saves the IDENTITY information so it does that automatically. I tried both pidgin, weeechat and hexchat and all of them are a bit weird.

Looking forward for answers.

Comment: https://github.com/nugget/irssi-nickserv

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure for all these you mentioned there's the option to automatically send commands like `/msg NICKSERV IDENTIFY` after connecting to a server.

The functionality you're looking for is already there!

Don't forget that Nickserv is not a standardized thing – every server might have a different functionality that fulfills that role – and that lack of standardization is probably why clients don't do this automatically: it might break in too many places. So, they rather let you define the  command that needs to be sent – there's no way for the client to know that.

All in all, IRC (as you currently use it) is a really old, and insufficient for modern usage, protocol. Which you can see from the fact that user authentication isn't a standardized feature, but something that you need to send some messages to some bot – and everyone's free to just build the bot they think is right for them!

IRCv3 tries to modernize IRC by adding formalized functionality on top of the old IRC. For this particular use case, [there's a standard for user authentication in the making](https://ircv3.net/specs/extensions/account-registration), but it's not ready yet.

I'll be honest, from a *purely technical* (not saxing anything about the social, not organizational) point of view, IRC is dead. It's not a good idea. The coherence protocols is not what users need. The fact that you need a standing connection to the server to not miss messages, or a "bouncer", which emulates that, which every advanced user I know of uses, is a pretty good indication that it's also not the protocol you might want to use in the future. I *hope* IRCv3 changes that, but with every day, that hope loses foundation. I'm not much on IRC anymore – matrix, also with bridges towards IRC – is a system that much more fulfills user's needs. (Hint: I'd try getting an account on matrix.org, and joining IRC through that, e.g., `/join #gnuradio:libera.chat`; that also has that NICKSERV authentication support I mentioned above.)